# CSS and LESS files are ignored in custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme, css, less

I'm trying to customize this component:

[image]

As I read from the documentation, in order to override the style of this search bar you need to create a folder called `Magento_Search` and add an _extend.less file in `web/css/source/` but nothing happens. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Have you run the deployment commands?

Comment: if you talk about `setup:static-content:deploy`, yes. I've tried also with -f option since I'm in developer mode

Comment: Try to remove the pub/static/frontend folder and run the command again.

Answer (score 1):

**Override /vendor/magento/module-search/ module with Magento_Search module from your custom theme folder.**

Answer (score 0):

as per your screenshot  can see only blank theme applies, and your theme consider as a virtual theme

so go to `theme` table

> SELECT * FROM `theme`

and check `type` column

> if your theme `type` column has 1 value then set it as 0

and then run

> php bin/magento s:s:d -f